# Add prefixes to id's and names of viewmodel fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor-3

In my project I use a lot of views/forms that are loaded dynamically. In my forms there are a lot of fields generated by using `@Html.TextBoxFor()` and then `@Html.IdFor(), @Html.NameFor()` are used in my javascript logic.

Some of my view models have fields with the same name (Id, Name, Description, etc), so if I have 2 forms with such view models on 1 page then I have a problem (same id attribute used for more than one element).

So I'm wondering if I can add some serverside metadata/attribute to my viewmodels with a prefix that will be added to generated id's and names? Or if there is another solution that doesn't require renaming my viewmodels or views.

Comment: You can reduce the occurrence of this problem by using editor templates. To control the behavior yourself, you can set `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix`. You then need to instruct the model binder what prefix you used, so this can get tricky if you are mixing field prefixes. Example: `public ActionResult _Edit( [Bind( Prefix = "MyPrefix" )] AModel model )`

Comment: It looks like that will require passing whole models inside actions (or duplicating actions), which doesn't look like a good approach in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.id,new {@class="class",id=[but here the id you want]})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "name" attribute of your inputs in your javascript code... those attributes are generated automatically.

If you have a composed ViewModel like this:

```
public class MyViewModel{
   public MySecondModel Sencond {get; set;}
   public MySecondModel Third {get; set;}
}

public class MySecondModel {
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

Then you use it in your views like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Second.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Third.Name)
```

The name attribute will became:  "`Second_Name`" and "`Third_Name`"

So... it will not repeat.

Comment: My bad, I guess I didn't explain the problem well. My view models are not composed. They are separate. Let's say I have `Employee` edit view on a page with `Id, Name, etc` fields and via ajax on the same page the user decided to load a form to create a new `Department` with `Id, Name, etc` fields. Let's assume that `Employee` and `Department` controllers are unrelated.

Comment: OK. Then, as in the views you are supposed to use ViewModels, you have all the freedom to rename the properties using a prefix... then the models can remain with the properties with its original duplicated values. This is not a tech suggestion, but will work :)